# Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in \wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 929

Tags: wp-cron, http, wp-debug

I'm writing a theme and almost every time I reload a page, WordPress is giving the following error

> Warning: fopen(http://localhost/wordpress/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1373799734.2041289806365966796875): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in D:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 92

As can be seen I have enabled `WP_DEBUG`. Here is a screenshot of the warning window (click to zoom):

[image: warning]

I'd provide further information but I have to know what exactly as I have no idea where the problem may lie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been reported here : [trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11831)

> Sometimes, HTTP requests fail. In this case, in particular, on
>   localhost. That's part of the reason why we suppress them. I've
>   personally never seen this. I think it's isolated to this server
>   configuration.
>   (Nacin)

Comment: Thanks for the directions! I solved it by uncommenting php_curl.dll in php.ini following the instructions in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486592/wamp-curl-installation